# Wrap a Python class in an asynchronous PyQt class

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am developing my pet project. It is a small app which downloads my inbox folder from Facebook. I want it to be available in both CLI and GUI (in PyQt) mode. My idea was that I write a class  for the communication, and then the front-ends. I know that the downloading process is blocking which is not problem in CLI mode but it is in GUI.
I know that there is `QNetworkAccessManager` but I would have to re-implement the class that I have already written and then maintain two classes the same time.

I was searching for a while and I came up with one solutions where I subclass `QObject` and my `FB` class, implement the signals, than create a `QThread` object and use `moveToThread()` method which would be OK, but I must take care of creating and stopping the tread.

Is it possible to wrap my Python class to something to make it behave like `QNetworkAccessManager`? So the methods would return immediately and the object will emit signals when the data is ready.

**Update**
Thank you the comments. I have 2 main classes. The first is called `SimpleGraph` which just hides `urllib2.urlopen()`. It prepares the query and returns the decoded json got from Facebook. The actual work is happening in `FBMDown` class:

```
class FBMDown(object):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.graph = SimpleGraph(token)
        self.last_msg_count = 0

    def _message_count(self, thread_id):
        #TODO: Sanitize thread_id
        p = {'q': 'SELECT message_count FROM thread WHERE thread_id = {0} LIMIT 1'.format(thread_id)}
        self.last_msg_count = int(self.graph.call(params=p, path='fql')['data'][0]['message_count'])
        return self.last_msg_count
```

So here when `_message_count` is called it returns the number of messages of the given thread id. This method works great in CLI mode, blocking is not a problem there.
I want to wrap this class into a class (if it is possible) which works asynchronous like `QNetworkAccessManager`, so it would not block the GUI but it would emit a signal when the data is ready.
The only technique I know now is to subclass `QObject`. It looks like this:

```
class QFBMDown(QtCore.QObject):
    msg_count_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def get_msg_count(self):
        #Here happens the IO
        time.sleep(2)
        self.msg_count_signal.emit(1)
```

And this is my Windows class:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.button_getmsgcount = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.i = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.block_indicator)
        self.timer.start(20)

        #self.worker = QtCore.QThread()
        self.fbobj = QFBMDown()
        #self.fbobj.moveToThread(self.worker)
        #self.worker.start()

        self.button_getmsgcount.clicked.connect(self.fbobj.get_msg_count)
        self.fbobj.msg_count_signal.connect(self.show_msg_count)

    def block_indicator(self):
        self.button_getmsgcount.setText(str(self.i))
        self.i += 1

    def show_msg_count(self, data):
        print 'Got {0} msgs in the thread'.format(data)
```

Now when I press the button the GUI blocks. If I de-comment line 13, 15, 16 (where I create a thread, move `fbobj` into this thread then start it) it does not block, it works nearly as I want but I have to do everything by hand every time and I have to take care of shutting down the thread (now I implement `QMainWindow`'s  `closeEvent` method where I shut down the thread before quit but I'm sure that this is not the right way to do).

Is it even possible what I want to do? I would not want to implement a new class and then maintain two classes which are doing the same thing.
The reason I am so insisted to do it like this is to make my app work without Qt but give a nice gui for those who don't want to type command line arguments.

Comment: You can Python `treading` or `asyncore` modules instead of `QThread`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Simplified versions of the code you are working on are much appreciated :)